# How to enable Docusign Connect

Tags: docusignapi

We have a business account and would like to use the Docusign Connect Feature. Is it necessary to go with an enterprise plan to use Docusign Connect.We do not require the other features that come with the enterprise plan.

Answer (score 0):

In our demonstration sandbox environment, Connect is enabled by default and can be configured and tested.

The best answer to your question around business plans vs enterprise plans for production use is to [talk to a support representative or your account manager](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-upgrade-or-change-my-DocuSign-plan).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I was wondering the same thing about the demo environment. It looked like it was enabled by default, but I wasn't sure.